# RestFULL Api with many Models (Android)

Tags: android, json, rest, pojo

I Have problem with understanding some questions about Rest API's. 
I made 2 apps using JSON and POJO. In this case I had one BIG JSON file and it was enough to use Retrofit and go ahead with app.

Today I found another challenge. I want To use Api From HitBTC :

https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/explore/

I don't know which repositories I need to use to display basic currency information in the application. Could You help me to understand this library?

thanks for any tips ;)

Comment: These endpoints seems to return currency info: `GET /public/currency`
 and `GET /public/currency/{currency}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These endpoints seems to return currency info: `GET /public/currency` and `GET /public/currency/{currency}`

so for a JSON listing all the currencies, try to query

```
https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/public/currency
```

and for a specific currency

```
https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/public/currency/{currency}
```

so for example for Ethereum

```
https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/public/currency/ETH
```

Comment: Simply reply is the best reply :) Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'd write a module behaving as a WS Client of that HitBTC API. To do so, I'd follow [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html]) design pattern.

Comment: Thank You :) It will be helpful